# How do access sql developer plus from preferences?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to access the SQL* PLUS Option in preferences and I can't seem to find it.

I am trying to do as what my instructor tells me to do

> In the Preferences window, click the SQL*Plus option.
>
> In the SQL*Plus Executable text box, enter the path for the SQL*Plus 
>   executable. Note: To find the path for SQL*Plus: Right-click the SQL*Plus icon on yourdesktop, select Properties from the pop-up menu, and then copy the SQL*Plus path from the Target text box but do not include the /nolog  at the end of the Target path.
>
> Paste the SQL*Plus path in the SQL*Plus Executable text box.
>   [image: preference menu]

Comment: I checked version 4.0.3.16 and  4.1.1.19 and I don't see it in either. Maybe they're using an older version?

Comment: I am using the current version of SQL developer. The first step in the instructions are completely vague. I use the search bar to but nothing shows up!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There's no such thing as SQLPLUS activation in newer versions.